# Powershell get eventlog source

Tags: powershell

Another simple question for you, which is a tough one for me...
I am trying to check, if a source exist in eventlog. using this command to check:

```
$EventLogSource = "TestSource"
$EventLogsourceCheck = [System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists($EventLogSource)
```

If the source exists, then it gives "true". The problem becomes, if the source doesn't exist. In this case the variable $EventLogsourceCheck remains the same, as it already was. in commandline i see the error:

> Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "SourceExists" mit 1 Argument(en):  "Die
> Quelle wurde nicht gefunden, aber einige oder alle Ereignisprotokolle
> konnten nicht durchsucht werden. Protokolle, auf die kein Zugriff
> möglich war: Security." In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
>
> - $tdf = [System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists('sfdsf')
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SecurityException
>   ```

i want to suppress this message and if the source doens't exist, i want the variable $EventLogsourceCheck  to be false.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suppress the errors with a [Try - Catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.2) statement, if the `SourceExists` method fails and throws an error, your `Catch` block can return `$false`, for example:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$EventLogSource = 'Application', 'System', 'SomeOtherLog'
$EventLogSource | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        LogName = $_
        SourceExists = try {
            [System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists($_)
        } catch { $false }
    }
}
```

Comment: using try catch works for me.